# Sending email and insert to table

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have created a form, once people submit it should go to the email and insert to table also,  the second part is working, but it's not getting to configured email.  The code is below, I'm I doing anything wrong? I'm not getting any error by the way.

```
<?php
include"connect.php";

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "myemail@gmail.com"; 
$email_subject = "Here is a message for you"; 


function died($error) { 
echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. "; 
echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />"; 
echo $error."<br /><br />"; 
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />"; 
die(); 
} 


if(!isset($_POST['name']) || 
!isset($_POST['vehicleN']) || 
!isset($_POST['pickup']) || 
!isset($_POST['pickup_date']) || 
!isset($_POST['pickup_time']) || 
!isset($_POST['return']) || 
!isset($_POST['return_date']) || 
!isset($_POST['return_time']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||  
!isset($_POST['mobile']) || 
!isset($_POST['message'])) { 
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
} 

$vehitype=$_POST['vehicleN'];
$pickup=$_POST['pickup'];
$pdate=$_POST['pickup_date'];
$ptime=$_POST['pickup_time'];
$return=$_POST['return'];
$rdate=$_POST['return_date'];
$rtime=$_POST['return_time']; 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_from = $_POST['email']; 
$mobile = $_POST['mobile']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$error_message = ""; 
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/'; 
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) { 
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />'; 
} 
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/"; 
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) { 
$error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />'; 
}   
if(strlen($message) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />'; 
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) { 
died($error_message); 
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";     
function clean_string($string) { 
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href"); 
return str_replace($bad,"",$string); 
}
$email_message .= "Vehicle: ".clean_string($vehicleN)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "pickup: ".clean_string($pickup)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "pickup-date: ".clean_string($pickup_date)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "pickup-time: ".clean_string($pickup_time)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "return: ".clean_string($return)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "return-date: ".clean_string($return_date)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "return-time: ".clean_string($return_time)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($mobile)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n"; 

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

$query="insert into booking set vehiType='$vehitype', datePick='$pdate',timePick='$ptime',dateRet='$rdate',timeRet='$rtime', name='$name', email='$email_from', mob='$mobile', message='$message', areaPick='$pickup', areaRet='$return' ";

mysql_query ($query) or die ('could not updated:'.mysql_error());
header ('Location:sucess.php');
exit()
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you echo out the `$headers` variable to check it looks right? Your use of mail seems ok otherwise. Take the "@" off before `mail` while testing, as it will suppress any error you'd be getting. Also check the return value of `mail` - if it's true, but your emails not getting through, it's something to do with the mail server rather than your code. If that's the case, there's a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044035/mail-not-sending-mail-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Not know for sure if this is the cause of problem, but there is no "died()" function in PHP; try replace " died() " with `die()` or `exit()`.

Comment: died() is declared within the OP's script