# PHP feedback form not sending email

Tags: php, html, email

I have created a feedback form for a website, the below code executes when i try to send the form and comes back as been completed successfully but when I check my emails no email has been received. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML form:**

```
<form action="send_form_email.php" method="post" name="contactform">
        <table width="450px">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                <input maxlength="50" name="first_name" size="30" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><label for="last_name">Last Name *</label> </td>
                <td valign="top">
                <input maxlength="50" name="last_name" size="30" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><label for="email">Email Address *</label> </td>
                <td valign="top">
                <input maxlength="80" name="email" size="30" type="text"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                <input maxlength="30" name="telephone" size="30" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><label for="comments">Comments *</label> </td>
                <td valign="top">
                <textarea cols="25" maxlength="1000" name="comments" rows="6"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['email'])) { 

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED 
    $email_to = "email"; 
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line"; 


    function died($error) { 
        // your error code can go here 
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. "; 
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />"; 
        echo $error."<br /><br />"; 
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />"; 
        die(); 
    } 

    // validation expected data exists 
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) || 
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) || 
        !isset($_POST['email']) || 
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) || 
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) { 
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');        
    } 

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required 
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required 
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required 
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required 
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required 

    $error_message = ""; 
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/'; 
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) { 
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />'; 
  } 
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/"; 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) { 
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />'; 
  } 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) { 
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />'; 
  } 
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) { 
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />'; 
  } 
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) { 
    died($error_message); 
  } 
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n"; 

    function clean_string($string) { 
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href"); 
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string); 
    } 

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n"; 
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n"; 
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n"; 
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n"; 
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n"; 


// create email headers 
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);   
?> 


Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon. 

<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: May you check in spam or other folders because many time the mail goes to any where else not in Inbox ....

Comment: I have already checked my spam

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044035/mail-not-sending-mail-in-php

Comment: better use phpmailer for mailing. mail() actually doesn't sends mail.

Answer (score 0):

check this code may be this will help you.

```
 // create email headers 
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 

          if(mail($email_to,  $email_subject, $email_message))
                  {

                        echo "<script>self.location='thanku.php'</script>";                                         
                       }
```