# PHP contact form functionality

Tags: php

```
$from = "from@domain.com";
    $to =  "myemail@email";
    $subject ="Contact Form";
    $message ="<p>Item Name: $itemname.</p>
    <p>Brand: $brandname.</p>
    <p>Description: $description.</p>
    <p>Availability: $availability.</p>
    <p>Contact Person: $contact</p>
    <p>Email: $email</p>
    <p>Location: $location</p>
    ";

      $boundary =  md5(time());
        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "From:".$from."\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

        //plain text 

        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit"."\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message."."\r\n";

        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= $message ."\r\n"; 

        //attachment
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";

        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n\r\n";

        $body .= $encoded_content ."\r\n";


        if (@mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        $resultMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You. Your message has been sent</div>';
    } else {
            $resultMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry Please Try Again.</div>';
    }
 }
```

This is my form PHP code. It is used by my logged in users so users usually signup by choosing username>email>password and register then they log in and see this contact form. so I want that when they submit a form , PHP should send their Username and Email. How can I do that?

Comment: Send them where? For what purpose? What have you tried?

Comment: Look there -->[@mail not sending mail in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044035/mail-not-sending-mail-in-php)

Comment: I mean when user submit form their username should be added automatically on on email I receive because of course they have to sign in to user my form... On registration their username is stored on database

Comment: Well, when they sign up you could cookie their username and email, or use localstorage, so they're always easily available - there's a lot of ways to achieve this - bit of a broad question

Comment: is there any post you can share so I can get started on this?

Comment: How do you store and retrieve user informations in your script?